# Cordova Ionic NFC tag write : Tag capacity is 0 bytes?

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, phonegap-plugins, nfc

I am currently trying to implement a simple read/write functionality in my native cordova app, and everytime i attempt to either erase or write in a tag, I get the following error : `Tag capacity is 0 bytes, message is 4 bytes.`

For inforation purpose, the tags I have with me are those : https://www.amazon.ca/Robojax-chain-13-56Mhz-Arduino-Raspberry/dp/B079Q9RYL3/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1527781307&sr=8-1&keywords=nfc+tags+keychain

I have ordered tags with a storage capacity of 8Kbit, so I do not understand what causes the write to fail.

I am using the sample ionic NFC project in order to write and read tags : https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/nfc/

Here is a small peice of test code to attempt write/read

```
this.nfc.addNdefListener( () => {
                console.log("Successfully attached NDEF listener");
            }, (err: any) => {
                console.log("error attaching ndef listener", err);
            }).subscribe( (event) => {
                console.log("received NDF message", event);

                if (this.isWriting) {
                    this.nfc.erase().then( () => {
                        console.log("Sucessfully erased the tag");

                        const a = this.ndef.textRecord("Hello world", "en", "usertoken");
                        this.nfc.write([a]).then( () => {
                            console.log("We wrote to the tag");
                        }).catch( (err: any) => {
                            console.log("we could not write to the tag", err);
                        })
                    }, (err: any) => {
                        console.log("Problem while attempting to erase tag", err)
                    });
                }
            })
```

There is a button in my UI that sets `this.isWriting` to true, so that we do not write accidentaly.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Currently using a samsung note 8

Answer (score 0):

Don't erase the tag, just write your message to the tag. If the tag is writable, the new message will overwrite the old message.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { NFC, Ndef } from '@ionic-native/nfc';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, private nfc: NFC, private ndef: Ndef) {
    nfc.addNdefListener().subscribe(this.onNdefTagScanned.bind(this));
  }

  onNdefTagScanned(nfcEvent: any) {

    // Create an NDEF text record
    const record = this.ndef.textRecord("Hello world", "en", null);
    // an NDEF message is an array of NDEF records    
    const message = [record];

    // write to the tag
    this.nfc.write(message).then(
      _ => console.log('Wrote message to tag'),
      error => console.log('Write failed', error)
    )
  }

}
```